# Tkinter Class and Button use

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble finding a way to accomplish what I want using buttons in tkinter. I am programming a multi-frame tkinter app, for myself, and each frame is a class, each class has buttons that I place on the screen in the `__init__` method. I am having trouble trying to link the buttons and the command functions together.

Example:

```
class frameHome:
    def __init__(self,parent, controller)
        self.frame=tk.Frame(parent)
        self.buttonOne=tk.Button(self.frame,text="Click Me") # I want to add the command here
        self.buttonOne.pack()
    def buttonOneClick():
        print("You clicked me")
```

When I add the command in the tk.Button() call it says buttonOneClick not defined. One video I watched said to add the function at the top of the code. I would like to keep the function as a method of the class for organization, as well as keep **init** at the top of the class and was wondering if there is a way to create a reference to the function so I can have it as a method after the the **init** method and be able to call it in the init method, because I would like the **init** method to create the gui and link all widget commands for that class/frame in it.

Thank you for any time and help that you can offer

Comment: Should be `command=self.buttonOneClick` and `buttonOneClick()` should be defined as `def buttonOneClick(self):`.

Comment: God do i feel silly. I forgot the self param. Thank you so much sorry for the silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

in your command did you write the command as command=buttonOneClick()? if that's the case then you should replace it with self.buttonOneClick()

Answer (score 0):

The answer I needed was that I forgot the self param in the buttonOneClick(**self**, msg) method.